# Development using Virtual printers instead of real printers

Tags: c#, windows, printing, print-spooler-api, virtual-printer

I want to develop an application that communicates with print spooler. The application is on .Net platform.

I want to have access to raw data of printed document but I want to use a virtual printer for this job. But I am unable to get the data from a virtual printer or raise an event whenever a print job is started. I checked the Windows system files and couldn't find a spooler for the xps printer.

I want to ask that does a virtual printer have spooler? If yes how can I access it because I couldn't find its spooler in the Windows files?

Can I use a virtual printer to develop an application that works with real printers?

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Windows has a spooler that serves all printers. There is not a separate spooler for each printer. Yes, of course you can use a virtual printer to develop an application that works with real printers. However, you won't be developing a virtual printer using .Net. A virtual printer requires a print driver and print drivers are native Win32 components. But then again, as I recall from your last question, you simply want to access raw printer data. You do not need a print driver or virtual printer to do that. You need a port monitor.